# Compare two arrays and getting the difference answer into an another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have two arrays and need to comparing them. Each element in the `P[p]` is compared with the each element in the `child1[q]`. If mismatch then that element in `P[p]` will be stored in the another new array. Where should I keep that `cout` statement for getting the mismatched number into an another array.

Thank you.

```
int P[ ]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};
int child1[ ]={3,7,6,5,8,6,7,2};
// getting the missing numbers
for(int p=0;p< r;p++)    // here r is size of the array i.e.8
{
    for (int q=0;q< r;q++)
    {
        if (child1[q]==P[p])
        {
            p++;
        }
        q++;
    }
    cout<< P[p];      // i have a problem here.where should i keep this statement for getting the mismatched number into an another array
    int M[p]=P[p]; //the result must be M[2]={4,1}
}
```

Comment: `if (child1[q]=P[p])` is assigning, not comparing, and there is `;` after `if` statement.

Comment: you don't need 2 `for` cycles, you can just use 1.

Comment: That sounds like the inverse of the set intersection, isn't? (In other words, `(a U b) \ ( a ^ b )` (`^` is the best operator I have found for set intersection :) )

Answer (score 0):

`if (child1[q]=P[p]);`

All I see you are trying to assign value from `P[p]` `to child1[q]`.. no comparison and also `p` will be changed every time because no code is associated with `if`..

check the below code..

```
if (child1[q]==P[p])
{
    p++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
int i=0;

   if (child1[q]!=P[p]);
     {
       cout<< P[p];   //<===Your cout statment goes here    
       M[i++]=P[p];
      }
   else
  {
   //do your increament
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying a cross check like this:

```
P=     1 2 3
child1=4 5 6
Checking= (1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),....
```

try this:

```
int i=0;
for(int p=0;p<r;p++)
{
    for(int q=0;q<r;q++)
    {
        if (child1[q]!=P[p]) //Mismatch
        {
            cout<< P[p];  //Printing mismatched value
            M[i]=P[p];    //Assigned to another array called M[]
            i++;          //Increments index of array M[]
        }
    }
}
```

**OR**

If you are checking values which have same position like this:

```
P=      1 2 3
Child1= 4 5 6
Checking= (1,4),(2,5),(3,6)
```

Then you don't have to use 2 `for` loops.

```
int i=0;
for(int p=0;p<r;p++)
{
    if (child1[p]!=P[p]) //Mismatch
    {
        cout<< P[p];    //Printing mismatched value
        M[i]=P[p];      //Assigned to another array called M[]
        i++;            //Increments index of array M[]
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u.i want first type of method u described in the example but i got  2 4 1 8..actual result is 4 1 .i.e M={4,1}. each element should be compared with every elements in another array thank u

Comment: `P[ ]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};` and `int child1[ ]={3,7,6,5,8,6,7,2};`. And the actual result is `4,1`? how?

Comment: thank u the elements in P[ ] should be compared with each element in child1[].  P[5]i.e., the element 4 in P[ ] is compared with all values in the child1[ ] .   thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
int P[]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};
int child1[]={3,7,6,5,8,6,7,2};
std::vector<int> M;

for(int p=0; p < r; p++)
{
   bool found = false;
   for(int q=0; q < r; q++ )
   {
      if (child1[q]==P[p]);
      {
         found = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if ( false == found )
   {
      cout<< P[p];
      M.push_back(P[p]);
   }
}
```

If you don't want to use a `std::vector<int>` for `M`, you can use:

```
int P[]={3,7,6,5,2,4,1,8};
int child1[]={3,7,6,5,8,6,7,2};
int M[8];

int mCounter = 0;
for(int p=0; p < r; p++)
{
   bool found = false;
   for(int q=0; q < r; q++ )
   {
      if (child1[q]==P[p]);
      {
         found = true;
         break;
      }
   }
   if ( false == found )
   {
      cout<< P[p];
      M[mCounter++] = P[p];
   }
}
```

Comment: The comparison needed to be reversed. Let me fix it.

Comment: thank u but i got this time 2 4 1 8..actual result is 4 1   .i.e M={4,1}. each element should be compared with every elements in another array     thank u